# Is $\cos\log a$ a transcendental for all nonzero algebraic $a$?

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers

Is this known? (excluding a=1 as was corrected in comments)

Comment: It's false for $a=1$.

Comment: The question should be about “all algebraic $a>1$”. Note that, if $0<a<1$, then $\cos\log a=\cos\log(a^{-1})$, and, as Gerry Myerson notes, the statement is false for $a=1$.

Comment: I need to know for $a>1$ (only positive solutions of the equation are considered), but case of $a\inmathbb{C}\minus\{0;1\}\$ is also interesting(what other exceptions have I overlooked?)

Comment: Please, user, edit the question so it asks what you actually want to ask. As it currently reads, the answer to the question in the title is "no," and my comment settles it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $a\neq 1$ is a positive algebraic number,
$$\cos\log a = \frac{e^{i\log a}+e^{-i\log a}}{2} = \frac{a^i+a^{-i}}{2} $$
is trascendental for the same reason that grants that $e^{\pi}$ is trascendental: the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem).

Comment: Тhe statement is true for $a\notin\mathbb{R}$, isn't it?

Comment: @user287791: yes, but in such a case you have to be careful in defining $\log(a)$.

Comment: But in Wikipedia "any value of $a^b$ is a transcendental number", i.e. for all values of $\log a$ expression $a^i\overset{def}{=}e^{i\log a}$ is trancendental and $a^{-i}=(a^i)^{-1}$. What do I understand incorrectly?

Comment: @user287791: there is a very little gap to fill from knowing that $a^i$ is trascendental to proving that $\frac{a^i+a^{-i}}{2}$ is trascendental, too. Can you fill it? Hint: assume that $\frac{a^i+a^{-i}}{2}$ is algebraic, deduce that $a^i$ is algebraic, derive a contradiction.

Comment: No, I talked about why the condition "positive" for $a$ is needed in the statement.

Comment: Substitution $x=a+a^{-1}$ allow to get from rational polinomial equation for x the equation for a.

Comment: @user287791: the only issue is that if $a\not\in\mathbb{R}^+$ you have to define what you mean by $\log(a)$, because $e^z=a$ has an infinite number of solutions over $\mathbb{C}$ (if $z$ is a solution, $z+2\pi i$ is a solution, too).